# Websites that give good Mathematical translation from French/German/Russian to English

Tags: reference-request

Could you mention some websites that can translate Mathematical sentences/words properly to English from a foreign languages like French/German/Russian to English ?

I have tried Google translator, but it kind of translates a Mathematical French sentence

"prendre l’intersection algébrique d’un lacet avec gamma" into "take the algebraic intersection with a shoelace gamma "

OR

"Formons SN le revêtement cyclique de degré 2N au-dessus de S" into "Let us form the coating SN cyclic of degree 2N over S", where clearly they are not much of a mathematical English sentences.

So I am asking for a specific wensite that does this job !

Comment: If you just want to translate individual words, pick a thorough Wikipedia article with some of the relevant keywords and flip back and forth between the English and, say, French versions.

Comment: Probably no algorithmic translations to date are very good.  That google's translator has this sort of problem seems universally remarked upon.  But you don't need to know much French to understand mathematical writing in French.

Comment: I would bet a large quantity of money that such a website does not exist.  Just buy a french/english dictionary -- mathematical french is easy enough to read that you don't really need to know any french grammar.

Comment: A similar question has been asked before: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9451/what-are-some-good-resources-for-mathematical-translation  You may not be happy, though, since its emphasis is more on technical terms, only suggesting google translate for overall structure.  Actually, I'm extremely impressed with how google managed your examples: for instance, "the coating SN cyclic" should probably be something like "the cyclic cover(?) SN", but otherwise its translation is better mathematical English than many students speak at first!

Comment: http://mathdict.chitanka.info/

Comment: I agree with your impression of Google Translate. I recently used it when I was
translating a Lebesgue paper from French, and found it only barely helpful.
Whenever I found a sentence that was really hard to interpret, Google gave
a very confusing translation.